# Mac Finder - Alternate default application?

Tags: mac, finder, file-association

Double click on an image opens the default application associated with it.

E.g. "jpg" opens with "Preview", but some times I need to open with an alternate application, e.g. photo editing software.

I don't want to change the "default" handling from "Preview" but may be with "Cmd-Enter" or "Ctrl-Enter" I want to open with another application instead of "Open With"->Select Application...

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: One idea is to drag the alternate application icon to the toolbar. That way you can drag the file to that application icon whenever you need. I used to do that with VLC for files that couldn't play or play well in QuickTime/Perian.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did also that, but it was tedious as I set my dock in auto-hide mode.

Comment: What I mean is having the icon literally in the *Finder toolbar*, rather than in the *dock*. However, I will concede that it is tedious compared to your desired keyboard-shortcut-type of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. It's trivial.

1. Use automator to create a service. In the top bar of your new service, select using the popups "Service receives selected files or folders in Finder"
2. Drag "Open Finder Items" from the left side into your Service. Using the popup, select your application.
3. Save service, "Open with Application X"
4. Open System Preferences, go to the Service in the list, double click right side of name to open the shortcut field, and hold your shortcut keys. <del>(<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> or whatever)</del>

Edit: In testing, it seems the Keyboard Shortcuts panel doesn't allow shortcuts with <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> No matter, just pick a shortcut you like. Make sure it's one not currently used by the Finder, though. This wasn't easy for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Not that I'm aware of*, however there is a possibility that you could [AppleScript](http://developer.apple.com/applescript/) something together.